# Correct way of using "not in" operator

Tags: python

We know that,

```
a = 1
b = 2

print(not a > b)
```

is the correct way of using the "not" keyword and the below throws an error

```
a = 1
b = 2

print(a not > b)
```

since "not" inverts the output Boolean.

Thus, by this logic the correct way for checking the presence of a member in a list should be

```
a = 1
b = [2,3,4,5]

print(not a in b)
```

But I find the most common way is

```
a = 1
b = [2,3,4,5]

print(a not in b)
```

which from the logic given in previous example should throw an error.

So what is the correct way of using the "not in" operator in Python3.x?

Comment: FWIW, the “correct” way to use it in your first example would be `a <= b`…

Comment: @deceze Right, but I needed a dummy example to highlight my point and so wrote it like this just for elaboration sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`not in` is a special case that simplifies to exactly what you tried first. Namely,

```
a not in b
```

literally simplifies to `not (a in b)`. It also works (slightly differently, but same idea) for `is`.

```
a is not b`
```

is equivalent to `not (a is b)`. Python added these because they flow naturally like English prose. On the other hand, `a not < b` doesn't look or feel natural, so it's not allowed. The `not in` and `is not` are special cases in the grammar, not small parts of a general rule about where `not` can go. The only general rule in play is that `not` can always be used as a prefix operator (like in `not (a < b)`)

Comment: What do you mean with "simplifies"?

Comment: I mean the word in the mathematical sense. "A simplifies B" as in "A reduces to B under some well understood set of rules".

Comment: "On the other hand, `a not < b` doesn't look or feel natural"   is  not even correct expression. Why it is has be felt natural  ? I don't understand the idea being natural in programming language. Using 'natural' word  as a logic is quite  uncanny.

Answer (score 2):

> what is the correct way of using the "not in" operator

There is only one way to use the `not in` operator. Your `not a in b` instead uses the `not` operator and the `in` operator.

[PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) doesn't seem to have an opinion about which to use, but about the similar `is not` operator (thanks Silvio) it says:

> Use `is not` operator rather than `not ... is`. While both expressions are functionally identical, the former is more readable and preferred:
>
> ```
> # Correct:
> if foo is not None:
> ```
>
> ```
> # Wrong:
> if not foo is None:
> ```

So I'd say `not in` should also be preferred, for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

`not`, [`not in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in) and `in` are all valid operators. Transitively, `not (in_expression)` is also valid

Correct way? Refer [Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/).

Answer (score 1):

First of all `not in`, is not a two separate operator, is constituently a single operator ,and also known as membership operator. There is another membership operator that is `in`. Membership operator has high precedence than logical `NOT`, `AND` and `OR`.

`print(not a in b)` -> This is actually first evaluating  `a in b` then result is  inverted by the logical 'not'  and then result is printed.

So as per your example it should print True as `a in b` gives `False` then it is inverted to `True` via logical `NOT` operator.

`print(a not in b)` -> Here python checks if `a` is not a  part of the `b`, if it is return 'False' else 'True` .

So as per your example it should return `True` as a is not a part of b.

I think `a not in b` is more clear and expressive than `not a in b`.I would suggest to use membership operator for testing  the  membership.

However the result will remain same for both  kind of expression but the process of evaluating is completely different.

Comment: *"completely different"*, this is not necessarily. At least in python 3.10, `a not in b`, `not a in b` and `not (a in b)` give exactly the same bytecode.

Comment: is evaluation process same for all ?

Comment: Priority is not important here. What is important is that python has made special treatment for this situation, so that the situation of first membership testing and then taking logical not will not happen in python 3.10, even if you explicitly divide this expression into two steps with brackets.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I want to read about it more. If possible for you could you please share some references.

Comment: It is just an unexpected discovery or the optimization of python. Don't worry about it. I believe it is *useless knowledge*.